# How can I detect the child element of a variable parent in E4X (Flex 3, specifically)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, e4x

I have XML that looks like this:

```
<question>
    <type_elt>
        <opt_out_flag />
    </type_elt>
</question>
```

`type_elt` is not an element name; it might be `<single>`, `<multiple>` or something else, determined at runtime.  How, given this, can I detect the presence of the `opt_out_flag` element?

I tried this (where `xml` refers to the `question` element):

```
if (xml.*.opt_out_flag) {
    do_something();
}
```

but even in cases without `opt_out_flag` the above expression returns `true`.  Obviously I'm missing something, but what is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you want to use `xml.*.hasOwnProperty('opt_out_flag')` rather than what you're currently using.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
xml..opt_out_flag
```

It will search for all occurrence

Answer (score 0):

Can you be guaranteed that `<opt_out_flag/>` will always be in the first child of the `<question>` element? If so, something like the following should work:

(disclaimer: I know this works with attributes, but I don't know if it will work with child elements)

```
if( "opt_out_flag" in xml.children()[0] ) {
    doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I can't guarantee that, no.  The grammar for the XML I am processing is underspecified and sort of ad-hoc, making it hard, if not impossible, to make solid assertions about the ordering or content of elements.

Comment: Ahh OK. Then I would think that quoo's solution is probably the way you need to go then. If that solution doesn't work, you may be forced to loop through every child element, testing for the existence of the opt-out flag - not pretty!

Answer (score 0):

can you use the descendants method (which recurses down the tree) to find the tag?

```
var optOutNodes:XMLList = xml.descendants("opt_out_flag");

if(optOutNodes.length())
{
   //do code here
}
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
var optOut:Boolean = xml..opt_out_flag != undefined
```

you can omit the != undefined part, but I would leave it there for readability.